# Sort a vector of strings based on a specified order

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a vector of strings which I want to sort based on a specific order of levels.

This is the order of my levels:

`x <- c("green", "red", "orange", "blue", "yellow")`

and I want to order my vector of strings: `y <- c("yellow", "orange")` based on the order of my levels in x.

So `y` should return `c("orange", "yellow")`.

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I also came up with `x[x %in% y]` for a possible solution

Comment: `y[match(x, y, nomatch = 0L)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by making y an ordered factor and then simply sorting.

```
x <- c("green", "red", "orange", "blue", "yellow")

set.seed(1066)
y = factor(sample(x, 5, replace=T), levels=x, ordered=T)
y
[1] red   blue  blue  red   green
Levels: green < red < orange < blue < yellow
sort(y)
[1] green red   red   blue  blue 
Levels: green < red < orange < blue < yellow
```